# Problem with audio device es8316 and bluetooth r8723bs (Ubuntu 18.04 installed in Yepo 737s)

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I have a Yepo 737s (Intel® Atom™ x5-Z8350 CPU and Intel SST audio and Realtek r8723bs wlan+BT) and I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.

Wifi is OK ;-D

BT is not recognized :-(

Sound is recognized:  “Analog Output Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers" but no sound speakers and no sound headphones ...

Answer (score 0):

See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391606 for fixing the sound problem.
The r8723bs driver in the 18.04 staging area doesn't include bluetooth.  There is a working bluetooth driver for the 4.4 LTS kernel series, but not the 4.15 series in 18.04 because of the changes in the kernel timer code.  linuxium offers a respin.sh script to take an ISO and rewrite it with some changes, and offers a 4.12 package for the drivers, (but that's not a LTS kernel series). See http://linuxiumcomau.blogspot.com/2016/06/running-ubuntu-on-intel-compute-stick.html
The Intel Compute Stick uses the same 8723bs as your laptop.
 Maybe dropping back to 16.04, with the 4.4 kernel would be a solution for you.